# Is there a word for a thing that is drawn?

Tags: terminology

I am looking for a word that means "something that is drawn." For example, if I have a list of things to be drawn (let us say a rock, a person, a tree, etc), these are all items that I need to draw. Do they have a term in art?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"subject" .. as in, "I will be drawing three subjects, a rock, a tree .."

OR (reviewing this caused me to think further about other possible answeres)

"i will be drawing three objects, an x, a y, and a z"
OR
"I will do a drawing of three objects, an x, a y, and a z"

I still cannot think of any single word for a drawn thing

Answer (score 0):

as described, they are a set of "Drawings" usually meaning more formal in style and presentation. Drawings would describe these as being "works of art" in their own right.

If they were roughed out, like quickly drawn items, the term "Sketch" would probably apply. These may still be appreciated as "works of art" especially if related to paintings or sculptures produced as a result of them.

A third category might be "Diagrams." This would apply to drawings of a more technical nature, describing a method and style of something to be considered with a view to future use to produce the item. A Technical Diagram" is an even more apt term, if it is indeed strictly to a scale and accuracy.

In a similar way, a Diagram might also be a "Map" of how to get from one place to another (literally or metaphorically.) A "Rough Sketch" or "Mud Map" 
would describe something the same, but of a lot less in scale and accuracy.

Sorry, there are so many ways to describe things, and the terminology can change dramatically, according to language, culture and geography.

Comment: This answer is incorrect; the OP was asking not for terms to describe the drawing itself but the thing that is drawn - the other answer correctly identifies this term as being *the subject*.